# Can app tested in iPhone run in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio

I write an audio player app with Xcode 6 in iOS 8. The problem is, when the audio player runs in iOS simulator, it can play audio in background, but when I test it in the real iPhone device, it cannot play audio in background. I wonder if Apple has limitation in testing in real iPhone device or I make some mistakes in settings.

Comment: did you enable "Audi and Airplay" in your app target capabilities->background modes?

Comment: yes, the "Audi and Airplay" is on